# glGetProgramiv returns a lower number of active uniforms, why?

Tags: java, android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, uniform

I'm doing a game framework for Android with opengl es 2.0 and glsl in java.
I did a method that automatically loads all the active uniform in the GL program to a java map with their locators. The problem I found is that the line

```
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv( this.m_GL_Program_ID, GLES20.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, total, 0);
```

is returning a lower number of uniforms that what I declare in my vertex shader. I know that some uniforms can be cutted of if not used by the compiler, but I tested this trying to get the m_Joint_Matrix[30] and it returned a value different from -1 (glGetProgram returned 28 active uniforms) so it´s not cutting of all these uniforms.

So... what do you think I´m doing wrong? This is the code of the function (note the var debug_value where I test my joint matrix uniform):

```
private void loadUniformCache(){
    int[] total = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGetProgramiv( this.m_GL_Program_ID, GLES20.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, total, 0);

    Map<String, Triplet<Integer, Integer, Object>> mapa_programa = m_Uniform_Cache_Store.get(this.m_GL_Program_ID);
    if (mapa_programa == null){
        mapa_programa = new HashMap<String, Triplet<Integer, Integer, Object>>();
        m_Uniform_Cache_Store.put(this.m_GL_Program_ID, mapa_programa);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < total[0]; ++i)  {

        int[] uniformType = new int[1];
        int[] uniformSize = new int[1];

        String uniformName = GLES20.glGetActiveUniform( this.m_GL_Program_ID, i, uniformSize, 0, uniformType, 0);

        int uniformLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(this.m_GL_Program_ID, uniformName);

        int debug_value = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(this.m_GL_Program_ID, "m_Joint_Matrix_Array[30]");

        // tupla de location, último valor asignado al uniform
        Triplet<Integer, Integer, Object> uniform_location_type_and_value = new Triplet<Integer, Integer, Object>(uniformLocation, uniformType[0], null);

        mapa_programa.put(uniformName, uniform_location_type_and_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I´m thinking that an array of uniforms maybe is returned as an only active uniform. Could I be right ?

Comment: Can you show the actual shader code (both vertex and fragment shader)? Given static control flow, the compiler may be able to eliminate indices in your uniform array that are unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this to happend is that, as I said in my comment, an array of uniform is reported as only an active uniorm.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetActiveUniform.xhtml

"Only one active uniform variable will be reported for a uniform array."